# How realistic is the film “Flash of Genius?”

Tags: realism, flash-of-genius

I recently watched [*Flash of Genius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_Genius_(film)) (2008), and I'm curious how close it stays to the real-life story of Robert Kearns, the man who invented the intermittent windshield wiper in 1969 before having the idea stolen by Ford and Chrysler.

Is there any information out there on how close to real life the movie is?

Comment: Reminds me of a girlfriend from 40 years ago, whose father had invented cat's eyes but failed to patent the idea. Talk about bitter...

Comment: @BCdotWEB I'm unsure why the question got downvoted, but thanks for the edit, what happens when I ask a question in a rush.

Comment: I'm not sure there are degrees of realism. Perhaps you can narrow the focus of the question to specific points?

Comment: @Paulie_D That would be a valid argument if we were talking about a well-known movie about which much has been written and researched. For a relatively obscure movie like this with a very limited amount of information out there, the question in the final line of the post is just specific enough to answer the question without running the risk of never getting an answer because the information doesn't exist out there.

Comment: https://www.basedonatruestorypodcast.com/73-flash-of-genius/

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I wonder that too.

What I know: Kearns had many more lawsuits ongoing than the film depicts because he pitched the wiper to multiple automakers, including Chrysler.

Kearns was also jailed for contempt of court at one point having something to do with his divorce.

Movies are a fantasy and time constrained so necessarily condense things (like the multiple law suits) and gloss over others, like his marriage.

In the film it seems sort of wistful, like there might still be a chance for him and Phyllis; in reality it seems she had to take him to court to get 10% of his financial award.

Kearns did have six kids; I don’t know how loyally they all stood by him as portrayed in the film. He died at 77 of cancer and Alzheimer’s. Enjoy life while you can, everybody.

Comment: Hi, the question asked for sources; can you identify where you found this information?

Comment: Sure. This is where I found that Kearns sued three companies and how he died: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kearns

Comment: And here is Kearns being jailed for contempt of court and having to pay Phyllis 10%: https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1990/08/25/inventor-released-from-jail-after-settling-divorce-dispute/bb97bf2d-594f-47b3-a0f2-530e67a18ac3/